# Streamlit deployment issues

Tags: streamlit

I have deployed my app via Streamlit sharing with the options:

“Only specific people can view this app”
And, 3 email address under “Invite viewers by email” in the “Sharing” section.
My App: https://kristalretriever.streamlit.app
My Github repo: GitHub - yashmehtakristal/KristalGPT-noauthentication: Kristal GPT Version (No Authentication)

The issue here is that whenever a user goes to my app and then signs in via Google with their email address, they cannot access the app directly.

I’m getting this error when I’m looking at developer tools:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feOQS.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMtbY.jpg)

Here’s what I have tried:

1. Using different browsers
2. Using incognito mode
3. Clearing cache and cookies
4. Ensuring the email I’m using to logging into the app isn’t already
   logged in concurrently (should not affect, but just tried)
   Disabling any VPNs and ensuring I have internet connectivity at all times
   Trying on my other devices

I have also looked at other streamlit forums and stackoverflow but no one had this issue. I have also looked at streamlit configuration page and didn’t find any setting that might counter this unusual behavior.

Yesterday, I tried and after 30 seconds to 2 minutes of this refreshing & redirecting error, it loaded my app. So I thought maybe just need to wait out (for an arbitary amount of time). But today, I didn’t even get access to the app after 2 minutes mark, which is really annoying.

Note, this app works perfectly when deployed publicly and loads in 5-10 seconds. I’m guessing this is purely a streamlit issue.

I am really depressed. Would really appreciate any help from some kind soul please.

Thank you so much for reading this post.

Orignal link to streamlit forum where I asked this question: https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/streamlit-sharing-not-working/54891/1